# Adding an offset to a category loop in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

In category.php of a WordPress theme, you have the following loop:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
// output posts
endwhile; endif;
```

How do you go abouts outputting this exact same loop but with an offset? I found that you can change the loop by doing a

```
query_posts('offset=4');
```

But this resets the entire loop and the offset works but shows all the posts from every category, so I get the impression the query_posts completely resets the loop and does it with only the filter you add. Is there a way to tell the loop:

"do exactly what you're doing, except the offset make it 4"

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: provide original code for your `query_posts` parameters

Comment: There are none, WordPress loads category.php and that is the loop (there are no query_posts() lines)

Comment: you must provide the category id in `query_posts` like `cat=3`

Comment: I thought about adding all the filters manually, but I wondered if it were possible to simply append a single filter (and override the one already set if there is one) to the existing loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all don't use `query_posts()` [see here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) instead use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Try this:

```
//To retrieve current category id dynamically
$current_cat = get_the_category();
$cat_ID = $current_cat[0]->cat_ID;

$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'offset' => 4,         //Set your offset
    'cat' => $cat_ID,      //The category id
));

if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
// output posts
endwhile; endif;
```

Yes as Wordpress stated:

> Setting the offset parameter overrides/ignores the paged parameter and
>   breaks pagination [(Click here for a workaround)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination)

Just follow the pagination workaround instructions and you're good to go.

Comment: This does work but breaks the pagination of the category, and I think it is because pagination only works with "query_posts" type of query. Is there a way to use WP_query but still have working pagination?

Comment: @user28240 Its not issue with WP_Query. Setting `offset` parameter breaks pagination with both method. See my edit!

Comment: I've just run into one last problem with that solution though and that is the fix does work but it applies the offset to every single widget in the sidebar too, so the "latest posts" widget which also uses new wp_query, has an offset now :( Do you know if you can apply that function to pre_get_posts() to a specific query and not all?

Comment: I think I figured it out, moved the add_Action just before the wp_query and then did a remove_action right after (wrapped the new wp_query in add/remove action) and it *seems* to work, please let me know if this is bad for some reason! Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post a full / fuller solution please? I'm facing the same situation, very new to Wordpress and am struggling to see how to apply dynamic offset values using the intructions from that link :(

Comment: @ChrisEdwards Just follow steps on that link that's the only solution.

Comment: @RahilWazir but how would I use a dynamic offset value, instead of setting it at a fixed value?

Comment: @ChrisEdwards When you do pagination you may have set the current page value just multiply it with your total limit of post and assign it to the `$offset` value using `$_POST` or `$_GET`. Like you do in Ruby and rails with `params[:page]`

Comment: Should call `wp_reset_postdata();` after using WP_Query